# spring bean with dynamic constructor value

Tags: java, spring

I need to create an Object which is in-complete without the constructor argument. Something like this

```
Class A  {
  private final int timeOut
  public A(int timeout)
  {
     this.timeOut = timeout;
   }
 //...
}
```

I would like this Bean to be spring managed, so that I can use Spring AOP later.

```
<bean id="myBean" class="A" singleton="false">
</bean>
```

However my bean needs timeout to be passed as a dynamic value - is there a way to create a spring managed bean with dynamic value being injedcted in the constructor?

Comment: You might be interested in [SPR-7431](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7431).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`BeanFactory` has a `getBean(String name, Object... args)` method which, according to the [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), allows you to specify constructor arguments which are used to override the bean definition's own arguments. So you could put a default value in the beans file, and then specify the "real" runtime values when required, e.g.

```
<bean id="myBean" class="A" scope="prototype">
   <constructor-arg value="0"/> <!-- dummy value -->
</bean>
```

and then:

```
getBean("myBean", myTimeoutValue);
```

I haven't tried this myself, but it should work.

P.S. `scope="prototype"` is now preferable to `singleton="false"`, which is deprecated syntax - it's more explicit, but does the same thing.

Comment: how could it be achieved with annotation ...? I mean @Autowired @Parameter1(value="xxx", type="String") <-- like this way?

Comment: @PatrickJeon This looks very interesting to me. However, I cannot seem to find any documentation supporting this, nor do I know what should be imported. The `@Parameter1` is not recognized. I am getting suggestions for both Hibernate and JUnit, neither of which seem appropriate. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: It is highly not recommended to use getBean(String name, Object... args) from ApplicationContext class in your code. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html
Read the last part of "Using the container" chapter.

Comment: @VadimKirilchuk: It says nothing about being "highly not recommended", it says "ideally". Using `getBean` is perfectly valid in some cases.

Comment: Well, when you use getBean in your classes you introduce direct spring dependency into your class and start using spring as a service locator instead of DI. It is ok to use getBean in spring related classes like custom BeanPostProcessorFactory or anything like that, but you should avoid it in other places. That's why I said "highly not recommebded"

Comment: How to pass dummy reference ..?

Answer (score 1):

Two options spring (no pun intended) to mind:

---

**1. create a timeout factory, and use that as the constructor parameter.**
You can create a bean which implements *FactoryBean*, and it's job is to create other beans. So if you had something that generates salt's for encryption, you could have it return from *getObject()* a EncryptionSalt object. In your case you're wanting to generate Integers.

Here is an example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/SpringFactoryBeanDemo.htm

---

**2. create a timeout bean that wraps an int that's dynamically set, and leave that in the "prototype" state so it's created each time**
Instead of going to the hassle of creating a factory, the EncryptionSalt object could just be declared as a prototype bean, so when it's injected a new object is created each time. Place the logic into the constructor or somewhere else.

---

It somewhat depends what value you want the timeout to actually be.

Comment: I want timeout to be a plain integer value. can you please give exmaples of both the approaches you mentioned here ?

Comment: I've elaborated in my answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Do it explicitly:

```
interface Bean {
    void setTimeout(int timeout);
}
```

---

```
class BeanImpl implements Bean {
    private int timeout;

    @Override
    public void setTimeout(int timeout) {
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }
    ...
}
```

---

```
<bean id="bean" class="BeanImpl" scope="prototype">
    ...
    <!-- Nothing about timeout here -->
    ...
</bean>
```

---

```
class Client {
    private Bean bean;
    public void setBean(Bean bean) {
        this.bean = bean;
    }
    ...
    public void methodThatUsesBean() {
        int timeout = calculateTimeout();
        bean.setTimeout(timeout);
        ...
    }
}
```