# Spring: how to instantiate a Spring bean that takes a runtime parameter?

Tags: java, spring, parameters, prototype

I've got a singleton Spring bean that creates a couple of tasks (`java.util.concurrent.Callable`'s) at runtime to do its work in parallel. Right now, the `Callable`'s are defined as inner classes in the singleton bean, and the singleton bean creates them simply by instantiating them with `new Task(in)`, where `in` is a parameter known only at runtime.

Now I want to extract the inner Task class to a regular top-level class because I want to make the Task's `call()` method transactional, so I need it to be a Spring bean.

I guess I need to give my singleton some kind of factory of `Task`s, but the tasks have to be prototype Spring beans that take a runtime value as a constructor parameter. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: @BorisTreukhov: this isn't a question about testing multi-threaded applications, this is a question about Spring. In fact, I'm going to remove reason #2 from my question because it distracts from the real problem.

Comment: See:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772585/spring-bean-with-dynamic-constructor-value

Comment: @Bossie ok I removed my comment, btw I think the simplest way is to create separate service beans, decorate their methods as transactional, inject them to your singleton and pass "in" parameter to service methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring's bean factory and new are mutually exclusive.  You can't call new and expect that object to be under Spring's control.

My suggestion is to inject those Tasks into the Singleton.  Make them Spring beans, too.

You should recognize that the Task itself isn't going to be transaction, but its dependencies can be.  Inject those into the Tasks and let Spring manage the transactions.

Comment: +1 for KISS. No reason to make things harder than they have to be, just create transactional services and inject those into the tasks.

Comment: "Spring's bean factory and new are mutually exclusive."  It may seem obvious to most, but for a spring newbie this was very important for me to hear.  It helped me understand what spring actually does.

Comment: But what If I don't know the number of tasks? I.e. someone submits a job with a number, say 10, and I instantiate 10 tasks? Could you please tell how to inject Tasks into Singleton in such case?

Comment: You should create a pool of Executors and let them handle your tasks.  Forget about Singleton and learn Spring.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach might be to use Spring's `@Configurable` annotation with load-time weaving, this way you can use `new` (instead of a bean factory) to create wired Callable's at runtime:

```
@Configurable
public class WiredTask implements Callable<Result> {

    @Autowired
    private TaskExecutor executor;

    public WiredTask(String in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    public Result call() {
        return executor.run(in);
    }
}

@Bean @Scope("prototype")
public class TaskExecutor() {

    @Transactional
    public Result run(String in) {
        ...
    }
}

// Example of how you might then use it in your singleton...
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
WiredTask task = new WiredTask("payload");
Future<Result> result = pool.submit(task);
```

See [this article](http://www.aspectprogrammer.org/blogs/adrian/2006/02/a_practical_gui_2.html) for more info. Note, you cannot use [@Configurable and @Transactional in the same bean](http://olafsblog.sysbsb.de/why-configurable-and-transactional-dont-belong-to-into-the-same-class/), hence the need for two classes. For that reason, this might not be the ideal solution if you have lots of different implementations of Callable (since you will need 2 classes for each one).

Answer (score 3):

Your singleton bean can implement BeanFactoryAware and lookup beans from the containing spring factory.

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryAware;

public class MyBeanFactory implements BeanFactoryAware {

    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) 
            throws BeansException    {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;     
    }

    public Task createTask(Task in) {
        return beanFactory.getBean("task",in);
    }

}
///////////////

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Configurable // unless using xml based config
@Scope(value="prototype") // tell bean factory to create new instance each time
public class Task implements Callable<Object> {

    private Object in;

    public Task(Object in) {
        super();
        this.in = in;
    }

    @Transactional
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        //do real work
        return in;
    }   
}
///
```