# Better way to inject runtime value

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am a Spring newbie. I found that sometime we need to construct an object using runtime data, but fixed value is used in constructor inject of Spring. I know I could create a setter method and change the value with it, but I don't think this an elegant solution. Could any one tell me how to do it?

Comment: Examples, code snippets, cookies, cash, etc might help.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Might be of help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772585/spring-bean-with-dynamic-constructor-value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943576/is-there-a-pattern-for-initializing-objects-created-via-a-di-container/1945023#1945023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally for this my preference is to make a factory like so:

```
@Service
public class RuntimeObjectFactoryImpl implements RuntimeObjectFactory {
    private final CustomObjectTypeA oA;
    private final CustomObjectTypeB oB;

    @Autowired
    public RuntimeObjectFactoryImpl(final CustomObjectTypeA oA, final CustomObjectTypeB oB) {
        this.oA = oA;
        this.oB = oB;
    }

    @Override
    public RuntimeObject get(CustomObjectTypeC oC) {
        return new RuntimeObject(oA, oB, oC);
    }
}
```

This can be configured in XML aswell (which I would generally recommend over annotations for wiring business services, but it's a more presentable answer here to use annotations).  So then at runtime:

```
RuntimeObject o = runtimeObjectFactory.get(new CustomObjectTypeC(...));
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Using SpEL => via Another Bean

```
<bean id="bank" class="UsBank">
   <property name="moneyLeft" value="100"/> <!-- initial value -->
</bean>

<bean id="bet" class="UsDollars" scope="prototype">
   <constructor-arg value="#{ bank.moneyLeft }"/>
</bean>
```

Let's say the `bank` bean is injected somewhere, so you have an access to it:

```
bank.setMoneyLeft( 100 )
Bet currentBet = appContext.getBean( "bet" )
```

---

#### Using SpEL => via Expression

If this argument can to be computed with an arbitrary expression:

```
<bean id="bet" class="UsDollars" scope="prototype">
   <constructor-arg value="#{ T(java.lang.Math).random() * 100.0 }"/>
</bean>
```

---

#### Using SpEL => via System Properties

If your use case allows to use system properties:

```
<bean id="bet" class="UsDollars" scope="prototype">
   <constructor-arg value="#{ systemProperties['moneyLeft'] }"/>
</bean>
```

to get the bean:

```
System.setProperty( "moneyLeft", "5000" )
Bet currentBet = appContext.getBean( "bet" )
```

---

You can read read more about [SpEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#expressions).

One thing to note about making a `bet` bean [prototype](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype) => if it is injected into another bean, it (another bean) also needs to be a prototype, or there is some AOP magic that can be used, but it may not be all that important in your case.

If the above bean does not have to be a `prototype` (which would mean you would only need a single instance of this bean, but *not* at the application context creation time), you can remove `scope="prototype"` and add a `lazy="true"`. That would tell Spring to only attempt to create this bean when it is first referenced.