# Dependency injection in Spring. not convenient regarding to prototype scope

Tags: java, spring, code-injection

Spring's DI works fine for singleton scope bean. However, regarding to prototype scope it is not convenient if the prototype bean itself will inject other beans. The thing is for prototype bean, I would like to create them using new keyword of Java with runtime constructor arguments which is hard to be statically described in XML bean configuration. Using new keyword makes the prototype bean out of Spring container, it is impossible to use Spring DI in them of course.

I am wondering how people solve problem like this? Of course I can use AspectJ to do myself injection as a compensation. But having two injection mechanisms is not an elegant solution to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark you prototype bean with **@Configurable**

Comment: This is absolute what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create prototype objects through `context.getBean(name)` or `context.getBean(class)` where context is `ApplicationContext` instance.

Another, perhaps even more convenient way is to use factory pattern with factory object being a singleton with all dependencies wired in and passing them to the constructed objects in `factory.createInstance(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Spring allows for passing constructor values to the `getBean()` method, check out this SO-Post:

[spring bean with dynamic constructor value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772585/spring-bean-with-dynamic-constructor-value)

Furthermore, what would be wrong about retrieving a bean from the context, that is just partially initialized and you are setting the runtime-parameters yourself via setters?

Be aware, that Spring-Beans are by default Singletons, so in your Spring-Config you would have to explicitely specify them as being prototype-scoped!