# Spring-Scala bean with dynamic constructor value

Tags: spring, scala

My question resembles [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772585/spring-bean-with-dynamic-constructor-value). I ask how to do it in Spring-Scala. I want to create a prototype using:

```
val applicationContext = FunctionalConfigApplicationContext(classOf[MyConfiguration])
val myService = applicationContext.getBean(classOf[MyService])
```

How do I pass parameters using the `getBean` method?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently (Spring-Scala 1.0.0.RC1) a way to do this using `FunctionalConfigApplicationContext` simply because the `MyConfiguration` that needs to be of type [FunctionalConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/springframework/scala/context/function/FunctionalConfiguration.scala) doesn't have the `getBeans(name,paramsArray)` flavour implemented that is the solution proposed in the linked question.

You can always perform this using XML configuration.

A working example here:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dimitrisli.scala</groupId>
    <artifactId>ScalaSpringIntellijTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.scala</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-scala_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repository.springsource.milestone</id>
        <name>SpringSource Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.springsource.org/milestone</url>
    </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>2.10.3</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dimitrisli.scala"/>

    <bean id="person" class="com.dimitrisli.scala.Person" scope="prototype">
        <constructor-arg value="John"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Person.scala**

```
package com.dimitrisli.scala

class Person(val firstName: String)
```

**Main.scala**

```
package com.dimitrisli.scala

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

    object Main extends App {

      val applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:config.xml")
      val me = applicationContext.getBean("person","overridenJohn").asInstanceOf[Person]
      print(me.firstName)
    }
```